# Modify a C# Manifest using the sha256 algorithm for the DigestMethod

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hash, manifest

I need to update a .NET 4.5.1 application manifest, ensuring that the DigestMethod stays as a sha256 hash.

Here's why: I initially deploy a WPF app with ClickOnce to a dev environment, and then a script configures, signs and copies the app to a particular production environment.  I have an existing script that does this, but after upgrading to .NET 4.5.1 from .NET 4.0 the script no longer works.  I think this is due to a change in the default manifest hashing algorithm from sha1 to sha256 in those .NET versions.

The relevant part of the script is very small:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities;
// This comes from Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll

public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // set up...

                DeployManifest manifest= ManifestReader.ReadManifest(manifestPath, true) as DeployManifest;

                // I perform some updates to the manifest...

                ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(manifest);
            }
    }
}
```

Even if I simply read the manifest and write it out again, without doing any updates, the DigestMethod Algorithm changes from sha256 to sha1 as shown in manifest files below:

Original manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="program.application" version="1.9.9.10" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="me" asmv2:product="program (dev)" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" />
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.5.1" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\program_1_9_9_10\program.exe.manifest" size="44259">
      <assemblyIdentity name="program.exe" version="1.9.9.10" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>0R79PRqWqhrE60GSHC/rE2WczQ4jqxCKBGr4lsjS4ZE=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Rewritten manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="program.application" version="1.9.9.10" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="me" asmv2:product="program (dev)" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\program_1_9_9_10\program.exe.manifest" size="44259">
      <assemblyIdentity name="program.exe" version="1.9.9.10" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>0R79PRqWqhrE60GSHC/rE2WczQ4jqxCKBGr4lsjS4ZE=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.5.1" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Notice the difference between the two is the change from sha256 to sha1 in the dsig:DigestMethod element.  Strangely, the DigestValue has not changed.  This ultimately leads to an error when I try to run the deployed application, along the lines of ""xxxx has a different computed hash than specified in manifest."

I have shown the Deploy Manifest here, but I see the same effect happening with the Application Manifest.

I think if I can write the manifest out with a sha256 hash, it will solve my problem.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the right hashes by using [Mage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than [ManifestUtilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.deployment.manifestutilities(v=vs.121).aspx).

Mage.exe has the -Algorithm flag to choose the hashing algorithm:

```
// -Algorithm <sha256RSA|sha1RSA>  -a
//     Specifies the algorithm to generate digests.
//     Example:
//        -Algorithm sha1RSA
```

The whole process I used to update my .NET 4.5 ClickOnce manifests (including signing them) was:

```
// Update the application manifest
// (I first had to strip the .deploy extensions from all the files referenced in the manifest for the mage tool to work)
mage -Update <applicationManifest> -Algorithm sha256RSA -CertFile <certificate > -Password <password>
// Then I replaced the .deploy extensions

// Update the deployment manifest (I didn't need to replace any .deploy extensions for this)
 mage -Update <deploymentManifest> -AppManifest <applicationManifest>
 -Algorithm sha256RSA -CertFile <certificate> -Password <password>
```

I used this method to run mage.exe from the C#, after including mage.exe in my project folder with 'Copy to output directory' set to 'Copy always'.

```
    private static void RunMage(string arguments)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "mage.exe",
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        };

        using (Process mage = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            while (!mage.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(mage.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
            mage.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

This link was helpful in figuring out what to do with mage: http://www.nullskull.com/a/1540/update-configuration-of-a-clickonce-wpf-application-using-mage-or-mageui.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it simply by using the overload that let you specify the target framework version:

```
ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(manifest, manifestPath, "4.5.1");
```